# Protobuf-net "a reference-tracked object changed reference during deserializartion" error

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am getting a  "a reference-tracked object changed reference during deserializartion" error when I deserialize the following object:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ZmqMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ZmqMessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2, DynamicType = true)]
    public object MessageBody { get; set; }

    public ZmqMessage()
    { }

    public ZmqMessage(ZmqMessageType zmqMessageType, object messageBody)
    {
        this.MessageType = zmqMessageType;
        this.MessageBody = messageBody;
    }
}
```

I serialize and deserialize in the following ways:

```
public static class ProtoBuf
{
    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T serializeThis)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<T>(stream, serializeThis);
            return stream.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Anything I am doing wrong here? 
Thanks

EDIT1: I found out that I don't get the error when I send a string such as "Test" in the MessageBody of the ZmqMessage object. However when I send an int such as (int) 1 or simply 1 it throws above error.

EDIT2: Here is the enum and a quick test case that demonstrates the problem:

```
public enum ZmqMessageType
{
    RawByteArray = 5550,
    ControlMessage = 5551
}

ZmqMessage testMessage = new ZmqMessage(ZmqMessageType.ControlMessage, "Test");
        byte[] byteMessage = ProtoBuf.Serialize<ZmqMessage>(testMessage);
        ZmqMessage deserializedMessage = ProtoBuf.Deserialize<ZmqMessage>(byteMessage);

ZmqMessage testMessage = new ZmqMessage(ZmqMessageType.ControlMessage, (int) 1);
        byte[] byteMessage = ProtoBuf.Serialize<ZmqMessage>(testMessage);
        ZmqMessage deserializedMessage = ProtoBuf.Deserialize<ZmqMessage>(byteMessage);
```

Comment: Did I really mis-spell it that way? Odd. Can you confirm exactly what version you are using, and what values you are using? i.e. what is `MessageBody`? Is `ZmqMessageType` and enum? if not, what is it? Basically, do you have a repro that is directly usable?

Comment: MessageBody is supposed to hold anything, but in my current test case I assigned a `string testMsg = "Test";'. ZmqMessageType is an enum, correct. I do not have a repo because it runs as part of a larger project but I could create a quick test case by just serializing and deserializing a test message. string  went through fine but as soon as I assigned to MessageBody an int it through this error message.

Comment: @Marc, I essentially already posted all classes needed to run, but I will just add the enum and a short test case to my question.

Comment: @Marc, I will get back to you on the version but I think it is v2.

Comment: oh, it is definitely v2. I mean more the .410 (or whatever)

Comment: @Marc, its version 2.0.50727. Any idea what else I can try to get to serialize/deserialize objects that contain a dynamic "sub" object? I am just puzzled why strings work fine but ints not given this is an error about "changing references", if strings through an error it would make more sense but ints...kind of confused.

Comment: 2.0.50727 is the Microsoft .NET version. Sorry to be a pain, but it would really help if I knew the protobuf-net version. Just right click on the dll and look in properties, or I think Visual Studio displays it on the reference. The *most likely* version is 2.0.0.480

Comment: @Marc, ups sorry my wrong. Its version 2.0.0.480. You are correct.

Comment: k, I'll have to take a look later.

Comment: @Marc, did you get any chance to take a look at this or are you able to give to give a rough estimate when you are able to check it out? I am just politely inquiring as I depend on it for a project and may have to look for a different solution (still using protobuf-net) if I cannot resolve this error. Cheers

Comment: @MarcGravell, just wanted to inquire whether you had a chance to take a look at this? I think it is a bigger bug in the framework because it seems to affect any value type parameter of a class that is marked "DynamicType" within the ProtoMember declaration.